# SQL Unpivot with CASE and LIKE Statement

Tags: sql, dynamic, unpivot

Looking for some help to UNPIVOT a table similar to the attached image.
I have two types of column names, either with "Sales" or "Staff" in the header, which I would like to combine into column just for Sales and Staff.
Ideally, this will be done dynamically, so that I am not specifying individual column names, rather just the criteria of what I am searching for.
The region can also either be dynamic, or accomplished through joining to a separate mapping table for metric -> region.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps `UNION ALL`?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

A generic solution uses `union all`:

```
select period, channel, 'East' as region, east_sales as sales, east_staff as staff
from t
union all
select period, channel, 'West' as region, west_sales as sales, west_start as staff
from t;
```

However, in a database that supports lateral joins, I would recommend a lateral join instead.

Comment: If this were a simple data set, yes, but in reality this will have hundreds of columns, all with either "Staff" or "Sales" (as examples) - so i would like to avoid specific column names - same goes for region

Comment: @JDR . . . You know what the columns are in a given table -- unless something is seriously unusual about your data processing environment.  If the issue is just typing a bunch of things, you can query the metadata tables to construct the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `unpivot` like below:

```
    DECLARE 
      @col_Sales  NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'',
      @col_Staff  NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'',
      @sql        NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

--different types of columns extraction

    SELECT @col_Sales += ',' + QUOTENAME(name) 
    FROM sys.columns
    WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('temptable')
    AND name like '%Sales%';
    
    SELECT @col_Staff += ', ' + QUOTENAME(name)
    FROM sys.columns
    WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('temptable')
    AND name like '%Staff%';

--dynamic sql
   
    SET @sql = N'SELECT [Period], Channel, replace(Region, ''_Sales'', '''') as Region, Staff, Sales
    FROM
    (
      SELECT *
       FROM temptable
    ) AS t
    UNPIVOT
    (
      Sales FOR Region IN (' + STUFF(@col_Sales, 1, 1, '') + ')
    ) AS up1
    UNPIVOT
    (
      Staff FOR Staffs IN (' + STUFF(@col_Staff, 1, 1, '') + ')
    ) AS up2
    
    where replace(Region, ''sales'','''') = replace(Staffs, ''staff'','''')  --crucial condition
    ;';
    PRINT @sql;
    exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Please find the db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b8f4622dc746607ae10b6bf5f36425d2)**.